# Is it possible to call a models field with a string ? Access a class member variable using string?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Suppose I have a model like this

```
class modelEmployee(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(modelEmployee, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,default=None,blank=True)
    introduction = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=False,default="")
    imageA = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='images/patient_images/blank.jpeg')
```

I know I can call imageA field like this

```
  inst = modelEmployee.objects.get(id=12)
  inst.imageA.save(content = someContent,name=someName)
```

Now suppose I receive the imageA field dynamically
Is there a way for me to call the field imageA like this

```
field = "imageA"
inst.[field].save(content = someContent,name=someName) #Access field using string
```

Comment: You are trying to look up a field given that field name as a string?

Comment: Yes I have a string which is actually the name of a member object.I would like to access the member object in this case "imageA" using a string.

Comment: If the dupe doesn't cover it, let me know...

Comment: I think thats what I am looking for, let me try it. Thank you

Comment: @StephenRauch that did the trick perfectly

Comment: Great, please accept the dupe...  Cheers.